# SQL Reconcillation Query

Tags: sql

Need assistance with SQL Query which can reconcile multiple entries (Buy/Sell) from one table to single line entries, tracking the amount bought and sold in Qty and Qty Left Columns:

I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Trades(
[Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ExecId] [varchar](35) NULL,
[Side] [varchar](6) NULL,
[Symbol] [varchar](35) NULL,
[LastQty] [varchar](35) NULL,
[LastPrice] [varchar](25) NULL,
[LeftQty] [varchar](35) NULL,
[Date] [varchar](35) NULL
)
```

with Entries:

```
 Id    Side Symbol  Qty    LastPrice  LeftQty   Date
 1     Buy    ABC   100     10.00       0       1/1/2011
 2     Sell   ABC   100     12.00       0       1/1/2011
 3     Sell   XYZ   200     8.00        0       1/1/2011
 4     Buy    XYZ   100     7.00        100     1/1/2011
```

How can I query table to produce a reconcillation report from the previous data as follows:

```
 Id  Side  Symbol  EntQty  EntPrice EntQty EntLeft ExtSide ExtQty ExtPrice  ExtLeft
  1  Buy    ABC     100     10.00   100     0       Sell    100     12.00      0
  2  Sell   XYZ     200     8.00    200     0       Buy     100      7.00    100
```

I need to combine opposite buy/sell entries onto the same line and then track the amount (Qty) remaining if the Buy Qty does not equal the Sell Qty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you can have 1 sell entry and 1 buy entry and always both. If you can have only one of them, you need to use a left or right join depending which one is always present.

The Id can't be returned as you have more than one and you don't have any criteria to select one of them.

EDITED: We obtain for each symbol:

- For boughts:  total quantity, average   price and the left quantity
- For sells: total quantity, average price and the left quantity
- The remains quantity (boughts total left quantity - sells total left quantity)

If you want an entry for each different pair buy-sell, you would need something to join the pair of entries (some common field). As you haven't got any field to join them, I think it is no possible to do on this way.

You can obtain all the info for each symbol on a single row, as the query does.

```
SELECT s.Symbol as Symbol, 
       b.SQty as EntQty, b.APrice as EntPrice, b.SLeft as EntLeft,
       s.SQty as ExtQty, s.APrice as ExtPrice, s.SLeft as ExtLeft,
       b.Qty - s.Qty as Remain                  
  FROM 
      (SELECT Symbol, 
              sum(Qty) as SQty, avg(Price) as APrice, sum(LeftQty) as SLeft 
         FROM Trades WHERE Side = 'Sell' GROUP BY Symbol) s
      INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT Symbol, 
              sum(Qty) as SQty, avg(Price) as APrice, sum(LeftQty) as SLeft 
         FROM Trades WHERE Side = 'Buy' GROUP BY Symbol) b
      ON s.Symbol = b.Symbol
```

Comment: Borja, when you say 'only one of them'...there would be hundreds actually, but they should have a match (ie.. 1 buy for 1 sell) is that what you mean?

Comment: This query works if for a given symbol you only have a 1 buy and 1 sell. If it is not your case, the query will need changes

Comment: do you mean 1 entry buy per symbol and 1 entry sell per symbol or do you mean 1 buy symbol entry for every 1 sell symbol entry but there could be multiple pairs of entries?

Comment: Buff :( Example: for symbol A you have 1 buy entry and 1 sell entry, or for the symbol A you have n buy entries and n sell entries. If you have n instead of 1, I will change the query accordingly to it, but I need to know if as final price you will need the sum (its the total price of the entry) or you need the average value (its the price per item of the entry).

Comment: Thanks Borja... I think I am not 100% clear.  The transaction report / query should combine 1 entry per symbol BUY for 1 entry per symbol SELL as long as the Qty of Buy => Qty for Sell... THEN for the next BUY Entry for the SAME Symbol, it will have another entry in the report/query that shows the same Symbol with a Buy and Sell.  The Entry Price and Exit Price Should Average ... not SUMM  - is that more understandable (this seems like it may be difficult !)

Comment: I changed it, Look if this is that you are looking for

Comment: You can group all the entries for the same symbol. But I think that you can't do it by pair of buy - sell because you don't have any common field to join each pair.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be:

- Group data by symbol and side,
- Do a self join on the result set on the results

For example:

```
WITH DATA AS 
(
  SELECT Symbol, Side, Sum(EntPrice), Sum(EntLength) 
    FROM Trades
   GROUP BY Symbol, Side
)
SELECT Symbol, -- Calculation goes here
  FROM DATA Sell
  JOIN DATA Buy ON Sell.Symbol = Buy.Symbol
 WHERE Sell.Side = SELL AND Buy.Side = BUY
```

If there is not always a buy and sell line for each symbol, perform a cross join and handle nulls properly in the calculations

Comment: Hi Johann, when you say '-- calculation goes here' what does that mean?

Comment: It just means I am too lazy to type the logic to substract the quantities and prices (mostly because Borja did that already) :)